# Generate a certain div with unique id or name or class? with PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This code below is showing the div that I want to generate when the button add section is clicked. I want to generate it uniquely for each section so that it doesn't exactly duplicate it or else it will mess up the data.

surveycontent.php

```
<div id='sform' class='tab-pane fade'>
           <br />
           <div class='col-md-12' id='clone-parent'>

               <!-- it is the following portion of HTML that is to be replicated? -->

               <div class='col-md-10 clone-section'><!-- removed ID, added new class -->
                   <div class='panel-group'>
                       <div class='panel panel-default'>
                           <div class='panel-heading'>Section 1</div><!-- this needs to change progammatically or via CSS-->
                           <div class='panel-body'>


        <b>Number of Questions: </b>


                <span id="ctr_num"> <input id="q_num" class="form-control" style="width:50px;" name="q_num" size="2" placeholder="#"/></span>
                <br>
                 <b>Select Category</b>

                <select class="form-control" style="width: 150px;" id="categorydd" name="catdd" onChange="change_category()">

                    <option>-Please Select One-</option>

                    <?php
                    $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_id, categoryname FROM category WHERE ParentCategoryID IS NULL");
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row["category_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["categoryname"]; ?></option>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </select><br>
                               <b>Select Subcategory</b>
                               <div id='subcategory'>

                    <select class="form-control" style="width: 150px;">

                        <option>-Please Select One-</option>
                    </select>
                                   <br />
                               </div>
                               <p hidden>Select Questions</p>
                               <br />
                               <div id='question'></div><!-- assigned as a class rather than id - can be targeted using querySelectorAll etc -->
                               <br />
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>

    <hr>


   <div class="col-md-2">
   <input type="submit" name="addsection" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Section" id="addsection" />

   </div>
```

My problem is the code inside the div, it is too dynamic. Here's the full look of my code including the php code behind those div id's for subcategory and question.

surveycontent.php

```
    <div id='sform' class='tab-pane fade'>
           <br />
           <div class='col-md-12' id='clone-parent'>

               <!-- it is the following portion of HTML that is to be replicated? -->

               <div class='col-md-10 clone-section'><!-- removed ID, added new class -->
                   <div class='panel-group'>
                       <div class='panel panel-default'>
                           <div class='panel-heading'>Section 1</div><!-- this needs to change progammatically or via CSS-->
                           <div class='panel-body'>


        <b>Number of Questions: </b>


                <span id="ctr_num"> <input id="q_num" class="form-control" style="width:50px;" name="q_num" size="2" placeholder="#"/></span>
                <br>
                 <b>Select Category</b>

                <select class="form-control" style="width: 150px;" id="categorydd" name="catdd" onChange="change_category()">

                    <option>-Please Select One-</option>

                    <?php
                    $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_id, categoryname FROM category WHERE ParentCategoryID IS NULL");
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row["category_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["categoryname"]; ?></option>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </select><br>
                               <b>Select Subcategory</b>
                               <div id='subcategory'>

                    <select class="form-control" style="width: 150px;">

                        <option>-Please Select One-</option>
                    </select>
                                   <br />
                               </div>
                               <p hidden>Select Questions</p>
                               <br />
                               <div id='question'></div><!-- assigned as a class rather than id - can be targeted using querySelectorAll etc -->
                               <br />
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>

    <hr>


   <div class="col-md-2">
   <input type="submit" name="addsection" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Section" id="addsection" />

   </div>
   </div>

    <br>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class=col-md-1><input type="submit" name="submit" id="btnSaveSurvey" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" /></div>


                <div class=col-md-1><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Reset Survey" /> </div>
</div>




</body>



</html>




<script type="text/javascript">

    function showUser(str,id) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    /* use id supplied */
                    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","hay.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }

    function change_category()
    {
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?category="+document.getElementById("categorydd").value,false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById("subcategory").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


        if(document.getElementById("categorydd").value=="Select")
        {
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML="<select><option>Select</option></select>";
        }

        //alert(document.getElementById("categorydd").value);
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?main=1&subcategory="+document.getElementById("categorydd").value +"&cnt="+document.getElementById("q_num").value,false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }


    function load_questions(){

        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php??main=1&subcategory="+document.getElementById("subcategorydd").value +"&cnt="+document.getElementById("q_num").value,false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


    }

    //subcat level
    function addQues()
    {
        var c = "insertQuesHere" + (parseInt(document.getElementById("q_num").value) + 1).toString();
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?main=0&addQues=yes&subcategory="+document.getElementById("subcategorydd").value+"&cnt="+document.getElementById("q_num").value,false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        //alert("insertQuesHere" + document.getElementById("q_num").value .toString());

        document.getElementById(c).innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;

        //alert("ajax.php?addQues=yes&subcategory="+document.getElementById("subcategorydd").value+"cnt="+document.getElementById("q_num").value);

        document.getElementById("q_num").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("q_num").value) + 1;

    }
    // category level
    function addQues_Cat()
    {

        var c = "insertQuesHere" + (parseInt(document.getElementById("q_num").value) + 1).toString();
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?main=1&addQues=yes&subcategory="+document.getElementById("categorydd").value+"&cnt="+document.getElementById("q_num").value,false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        //alert("insertQuesHere" + document.getElementById("q_num").value .toString());

        document.getElementById(c).innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;

        //alert("ajax.php?addQues=yes&subcategory="+document.getElementById("subcategorydd").value+"cnt="+document.getElementById("q_num").value);

        document.getElementById("q_num").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("q_num").value) + 1;


    }

    function checkValues()
    {

        var sameValue = false;
        var cnt = parseInt(document.getElementById("q_num").value);

        for (var i = 1; i <= cnt; i++)
        {
            var a = "question_dropdown"+i.toString();
            for (var j = 1; j <= cnt; j++)
            {
                var b = "question_dropdown"+j.toString();
                if(document.getElementById(a).value ==  document.getElementById(b).value && i != j)
                    sameValue = true;
            }
        }

        if(sameValue == true) {
            alert("No duplicate questions allowed.");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    function delQues()
    {

        var a = "ques"+document.getElementById("q_num").value.toString();
        //alert(a);
        var element = document.getElementById(a);
        element.outerHTML = "";
        delete element;


        document.getElementById("q_num").value = (document.getElementById("q_num").value - 1);

    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#execute").click(function(){
            var numQ = +$('#q_num').val();
            //Loop--
            for(var ctr=0; ctr < numQ; ctr++){
                var str = load_questions();
                $("#divQuestions").append(str);
            }
        });
    });



</script>
```

ajax.php (the code behind those div id's)

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imetrics");

$category= isset($_GET["category"])?$_GET["category"]:"";
$subcat=isset($_GET["subcategory"])?$_GET["subcategory"]:"";
$question=isset($_GET["subcategory"])?$_GET["subcategory"]:"";
$cnt=isset($_GET["cnt"])?$_GET["cnt"]:"";
$addQues=isset($_GET["addQues"])?$_GET["addQues"]:"";
$main=isset($_GET["main"])?$_GET["main"]:"";

if($category!=""){

    $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_id, categoryname FROM category WHERE ParentCategoryID =$category ");
    echo "<select id='subcategorydd' class='form-control' style='width:150px;' name='subcatdd' onchange='load_questions()' >";
    echo "<option selected>"; echo "Select"; echo "</option>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<option value='$row[category_id]'>"; echo $row["categoryname"]; echo "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

// for loading ques under Category already
if($question !="" && $cnt!="" && $addQues!="yes" && $main == 1){
    $i = 0;
    for( $i = 1; $i <= $cnt; $i++ ){
        $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT question.* FROM question LEFT JOIN category AS subcategory on subcategory.category_id = question.question_subcat WHERE question.question_category = $question AND (question.question_subcat IS NULL OR subcategory.category_id IS NOT NULL)");


        echo "<form id='ques{$i}'>
        <b id='labelquestion_dropdown{$i}'>Question #{$i}</b>
        <select id='question_dropdown{$i}' class='form-control' onchange=\"showUser( this.value, 'txtHint{$i}' )\" style='width: 300px;' name='question_dropdowns{$i}'>
            <option selected>Select";

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<option value='{$row['question_id']}'>" . $row["questiontitle"];
        }

        echo "
        </select>

    <div id='txtHint{$i}'><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
    <br /></form>";
    }
    echo "<div id='insertQuesHere".$i."'></div>";

    echo "<a href='#add_question' onclick='return addQues_Cat();'>Add Question</a> | ";
    echo "<a href='#del_question' onclick='return delQues();'>Delete Question</a>";
}

// for loading ques under SUBCATEGORY
if($question !="" && $cnt!="" && $addQues!="yes" && $main != 1){
    $i = 0;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $cnt; $i++)
    {
        $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_subcat = $question ");
        echo "
    <form id='ques{$i}'>
        <b id='labelquestion_dropdown{$i}'>Question #{$i}</b>
        <select id='question_dropdown{$i}' class='form-control' onchange=\"showUser( this.value, 'txtHint{$i}' )\" style='width: 300px;' name='question_dropdowns{$i}'>
     <option selected>Select";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo "<option value='{$row['question_id']}'>" . $row["questiontitle"];
        }

        echo "
        </select>

    <div id='txtHint{$i}'><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
    </form>  
    <br />";
    }

    echo "<div id='insertQuesHere".$i."'></div>     ";

    echo "<a href='#add_question' onclick='return addQues();'>Add Question</a> | ";
    echo "<a href='#del_question' onclick='return delQues();'>Delete Question</a>";
}


//add ques
if($subcat !="" && $addQues=="yes" && $cnt != "")
{
    $i = 0;
    $num = $cnt + 1;
    //echo $num;
    if($main == 1)
    {

        $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT question.* FROM question LEFT JOIN category AS subcategory on subcategory.category_id = question.question_subcat WHERE question.question_category = $question AND (question.question_subcat IS NULL OR subcategory.category_id IS NOT NULL)");
        echo "
        <form id='ques{$num}'>
        <b id='labelquestion_dropdown{$num}'>Question #{$num}</b>
        <select id='question_dropdown{$num}'". ($cnt + 1) ." class='form-control' onchange=\"showUser( this.value, 'txtHint{$num}' )\" style='width: 300px;' name='question_dropdowns{$num}'>
        <option selected>Select";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo "<option value='{$row['question_id']}'>" . $row["questiontitle"];

        }
        echo
        "</select>

      <div id='txtHint{$num}'><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
          <br /></form>";

        echo "<div id='insertQuesHere".($cnt + 2)."'></div>";
    }

    else if ($main ==0)
    {
        $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_subcat = $question ");
        echo "
         <form id='ques{$num}'>
        <b id='labelquestion_dropdown{$num}'>Question #{$num}</b>
        <select id='question_dropdown{$num}' class='form-control' onchange=\"showUser( this.value, 'txtHint{$num}' )\" style='width: 300px;' name='question_dropdowns{$num}'>
        <option selected>Select";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo "<option value='{$row['question_id']}'>" . $row["questiontitle"];

        }
        echo
        "</select>

      <div id='txtHint{$num}'><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
          <br /></form>";

        echo "<div id='insertQuesHere".($cnt + 2)."'></div>";
    }
    //
    //echo "<a href='#add_question' onclick='return addQues();'>Add Question</a>";
}



?>
```

I want to generate this div because the whole add section button purpose is like my first step to the skip logic conditional branching. So I need to have their id or class or name unique?

Comment: you already pass cnt from js and use it with number count to create a unique id with the count. so what is your problem? as you already used {$num} for every id.

Comment: I want to generate this whole code when the add section button is clicked. Like create another section of this while code. @MahipalPatel

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Try to avoid using IDs for elements that are going to be replicated because firstly it will potentially lead to duplicates that need to then be corrected to be made unique and secondly you will not necessarily know the new ID within your code when you need to use them next. A better solution - having looked at your code several times - to my mind would be to use parent & child selectors ( think `document.querySelectorAll` ). Your ajax functions are all over the place - most have no callback function at all and some have nested ajax calls. You should look at Promises or the Fetch API

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, I am using this method

```
var getUniqueId = function () {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10);
};
```

Example of generated ids `"t0917mk342", "z6teqwb2v7"` etc..

Comment: In my situation @Ankush Jain

Comment: In your situation you have both.

Answer (score 0):

in your file use one session counter variable to unique your div id like this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['divcounter'])){
   $_SESSION['divcounter'] = 1;
}
```

and then use this session variable in your add ques function like below

```
$num = $cnt + $_SESSION['divcounter'];
$_SESSION['divcounter']++;
```